# SQL Create table from surrounding rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database table ('map') with the following columns:

- ptID (uniquely identifies patients)
- uniid (uniqueidentifier for every
  row)
- time (have a new row every 1 minute)
- mapval (data point of interest)
- validate (0 or 1)

What I would like is a table with the preceding and following 30 mapval every time validate = 1. These 61 rows should come from the table 'map' and include all rows (i.e. when validate = 0 or 1, not just 1).

I have tried queries using lag/lead, but am having no luck.

Just FYI, once I have this table I plan to do some basic things to the data. Like an avg, median (with percentile_cont) and mode (with an ordered count).

At this point I can easily do the AVG with the table as is using the following:

```
 SELECT [ptID],[time],[mapval],[validate],
    IIF([validate]=1,   
      AVG(CAST ([mapval] AS decimal)) 
       OVER(
         PARTITION BY [ptID]
         ORDER BY [ptID] ASC, [time] ASC
         ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 30 FOLLOWING 
            ) 
      ,NULL) AS 'sixytminavg'
```

But unfortunately cannot do the median nor mode.

Longwinded, but I hope it gives all the information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me focus on this:

> What I would like is a table with the preceding and following 30
>   mapval every time validate = 1. These 61 rows should come from the
>   table 'map' and include all rows (i.e. when validate = 0 or 1, not
>   just 1).

You can get the 30 rows after each validate -- assuming there is no other validate -- by breaking the rows into groups.  The idea is to assign a validate group to each row.  And, you can do this by counting the number of times that validate is 1 before each row.  Then take the first 31 rows:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by grp order by time) as seqnum
      from (select m.*, sum(validate) over (order by ptId order by time) as grp
            from map m
           ) m
     ) m
where seqnum <= 31;
```

You can do this for before and after groups at the same time:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by time) as seqnum_after,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by time desc) as seqnum_before
      from (select m.*,
                   sum(validate) over (order by ptId order by time) as grp_after,
                   sum(validate) over (order by ptId order by time desc) as grp_before
            from map m
           ) m
     ) m
where seqnum_after <= 31 or seqnum_before <= 31;
```

EDIT:

If the validates are too close together, you an use a `join` approach instead:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by ptid order by time) as seqnum
      from map m
      where validate = 1
     ) v join
     (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by ptid order by time) as seqnum
      from map m
     ) m
     on v.ptid = m.ptid and m.seqnum between v.seqnum - 30 and v.seqnum + 30;
```

Comment: Great solution! It gets me very, very close. My issue is that rows with validate = 1 are sometimes within a few rows of each other, and I still need to analyze the 30 preceding and following rows.

Comment: Thanks so much! The join solution was close enough to get me there.

I'll write the final solution in another comment in case it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, maybe something like the following?

```
SELECT m.ptid, m.uniid, m.time, m.mapval, m.validate
FROM map m INNER JOIN 
(SELECT uniid
FROM map
WHERE validate=1) AS valids ON m.uniid BETWEEN valids.uniid-30 AND valids.uniid+30
ORDER BY m.uniid
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gordon for the solution. The only issue with it was that the first select limited the row_numbers to those rows that were validated as opposed to numbering all the rows and selecting the ones that were validated. I have added another nested select do achieve that. Not the fastest query, but I only have to run it a few times on our dataset.

```
select q.*, n.time rowtime, n.mapval rowmapval 
    from ( select v.* 
        from (
             select m.*, row_number() over (partition by ptid order by time) as seqnum
             from map m
             ) v
        where validate = 1
        ) q
    join
        (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by ptid order by time) as seqnum
        from map m
        ) n
    on q.ptid = n.ptid and n.seqnum between q.seqnum - 30 and q.seqnum + 30
        ORDER by q.ptID, q.time, n.time
```